# How to update a specific object inside an array of a JSON file?

Tags: android, json

format of my json file in internal storage is like,

```
{
"appointments": [
{
  "appointmentId": "app_001",
  "appointmentTitle": "Appointment Title1",
  "appointmentDate": "2017-11-25",
  "appointmentTime": "10:30",
  "appointmentStatus": "active",
  "appointmentType": "meeting",
  "reminder": {
    "type": "notification",
    "time": "10:15",
    "status": "off"
  },
  "appointmentDescription": "blablablablabla1"
},
{
  "appointmentId": "app_002",
  "appointmentTitle": "AppointmentTitle2",
  "appointmentDate": "2017-11-26",
  "appointmentTime": "09:00",
  "appointmentStatus": "done",
  "appointmentType": "exam",
  "reminder": {
    "type": "alarm",
    "time": "08:45",
    "status": "on"
  },
  "appointmentDescription": "blablablablabla2"
}
]
}
```

I need to update value of `appointmentTitle` which has `app_001` as `appointmentId`

my function is,

```
String configFileString = "";

            File configFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("/appointments"), "appointments.json");
            try {
                configFileString = getStringFromFile(configFile.toString());
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(configFileString);
                JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("appointments");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

What should be the modifications that I need to do in my code? please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just so that I understand your question; do you want to change the title of the object or values of the object?

Comment: @Nero i mentioned value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have , you just have to go through the array and update your data:

```
JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("appointments");
for(int i=0;i < array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = object.getString("appointmentId");
    if (id.equals("app_001")){
       object.put("appointmentTitle","your value updated");
    }
}

String stringJSON = array.toString();
//save your data
```